# Magento Custom Attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I have created a multi-website store in Magento with a custom attribute called `Bar-code` which is visible on product view page.

I just want to display this `Bar-code` attribute on a single website not on all the websites or web store.

How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with any built in feature, it would probably require overloading a template and checking against the website/store ID, which is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should set needed scope for your attribute:
   [image: Change attribute scope]
2. Go to edit product page and switch to needed website or store view level, set attribute value for this website/sore view. 
   [image: Set attribute value for needed website]
   For other website this attribute value will be empty.
3. In your on product view page template render this attribute only if it is not empty.